# How to update the view counter in symfony and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

```
/**
     * Lists all user entities.
     *
     * @Route("/article/{id}/{title}", name="article")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function articleAction($id, $title) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $article = $em->getRepository('TryoneeArticleBundle:Article')->find($id);
        if (!$article)
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('main'));

        if ($article->getTitle() != str_replace('-', ' ', $title)) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('article', array('id' => $article->getId(), 'title' => str_replace(' ', '-', $article->getTitle()))));
        }
        $keywordarray = explode(',', $article->getKeyword());

        $newview = $article->getTotalView() + 1;
        $article->setTotalView($newview);
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        return array(
            'article' => $article,
            'id' => $id,
            'keywords' => $keywordarray,
            'view' => $newview
        );
    }
```

This is my controller code in which i want to get the article form the database and increment the view.
But this code is showing a strange behavior some time it increments 4 time and 2 time and single time.

Am i missing something....? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not enough information provided. The increment looks fine. I'd suggest logging the code execution so you can trace what's happening. More than likely, this bit of code is being executed multiple times, if it's the only place incrementing this value.

Comment: why it increments randomly ? if code executes multiple time than why it increment randomly like 1,2,4?

Comment: Can't tell from that snippet of code alone. If it's completely random, then it sounds like there's more than one place where your object(s) are being updated. Maybe in event listeners. Maybe even something happening at the database level, like with a stored procedure.