# How to see authanticated user in annoymous section in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a little problem in project with symfony.

I am developing a article website in which normal visitor can see all the article without login and admin can login and add or remove article but admin can remove the comments that are marked as spam in article page after login.The problem is that i have allowed anonymous in article section (main controller) and if i login in admin section still session shows me anonymous user in main controller.? why?

```
 firewalls:
    admin_login:
        pattern:  ^/admin/login$
        security: false
    main_area:(article area)
        pattern: ^/main
        anonymous: ~

    adminrestricted_area:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: _admin_login
            check_path: _admin_login_check
        logout:
            path:   _admin_logout
            target: _admin_login
```

only page having `/admin` in url shows me the current logged in user but i want to access that user in `/main` but in session it shows me 
[image]

Am i missing something?

I want that if login it should show me the logged in user and if i don't this page should normally be accessed without login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony, you may define many area in the `security.yml` configuration.
But each area is separated. You may be authenticated in one area but not in the other.

In your case, your user is authenticated in the `admin_login` area, but not in the `main_area`, so Symfony's consider that you are an anonymous user.

If you need that your admin can be connected in the "public area", so you need to define a single area, and use the access_control. Something like this :

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: _admin_login
            check_path: _admin_login_check
        logout:
            path:   _admin_logout
            target: _admin_login
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: IMO to complete your answer is better to add also a reference to the [Firewall Context](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context), useful when is needed to authenticate an user to multiple firewalls with the same login access point.

Comment: @Yann do you know something about this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853652/how-to-update-the-view-counter-in-symfony-and-doctrine

Comment: I don't, I'm sorry. But I agree with the comments you got on this post. I have no idea why you got that strange behavior.